Inconsistent outbound IP address in VMs attached to multiple public load balancers in Azure
I created some VMs with VMSSes in Azure. I added them to the backend address pools of 2 public LBs.
In LB 1, I configured some load balancing rules: 1 for TCP to port 443 and the other for TCP to port 22.
In LB2 I have an SNAT rule for outbound.
However, when I checked curl ifconfig.me from some of the VMs, in this case I had 3 VMs, I got the public frontend IP of LB1 in 2 of them, and got the public frontend IP of LB2 in 1 of them.
This left me very confused - LB1 didn't even have an outbound rule. How come some VMs were using its public frontend IP?
Tried to look at the configs of LBs on the portal and didn't find anything unexpected.

You should have a route table resource associated with the subnet of the VMs. Ensure you have, and that there is only a single route for outbound internet traffic which is sent to the IP address of the desired load balancer.
Outbound traffic from the VMs which is data related to an inbound request will always originate from the LB IP to which the outside client connected. That's mandatory in TCP. But outbound initiated connections, such as your curl request, will be routed according to the route table associated with the subnet.
